What is the up-to-date style name for APA with Latex biblatex package?
I am using Overleaf to create a CV with Latex, and need to use APA formatting for my references. I've tried the below code, but the 6th edition is not the most up-to-date (7th is), and style=apa seems to have bugs in it. One of the issues is that I haven't been able to get my last name to be in bold (when writing the code to do so, that works with other reference styles) with style=apa. I haven't found examples of using APA in Latex and am grateful for any help.
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=apa6,url=true,doi=true,maxbibnames=99,sorting=ydnt,dashed=false,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

I think you could try biblatex-apa (https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-apa). It promises to format in 7th edition style. On ctan.org it is the package with the newest date for a version or an update.
